# Does dynamical system has volume preserving property in basin of attraction?

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, basins-of-attraction

I have a question on the basin of attraction: Does the dynamic flow on every bounded region inside of a basin of attraction has volume preserving property?

Comment: Take for example $x'=-x$ and look at intervals near the origin.

Answer (score -1):

Well, every point in a basin of attraction will get arbitrarily close to the attractor, that's what is meant by *attraction*. Hence every finite region within a basin of attraction will shrink to a point.

However, in a complex dynamical system there might be Siegel discs or Hermann rings that are conjugate to a rotation of the unit disc, see for example

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Fatou_components

As the dynamic is basically a rotation of the usit disc, restricting the mapping to such domains is volume preserving, but points therein do not converge to an attractor.